# ACF function with rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to create a function that adds the sample autocorrelations (ACF) to a fixed lag. I do not know much about the syntax of c ++, any idea of how to solve this error.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List acfC(NumericVector x, bool plot = true, int lagmax = NULL) {
  Environment stats("package:stats");
  Function ri=stats["acf"];
  List result =  sum(ri(x)[[1]]);
  return(result);
}
```

Expected output 3.579

```
/*** R
acfC(y,lagmax = 10,plot = F)

set.seed(1)
y = c(arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.7), n = 200),NA)
res = acf(y, lag.max = 10,plot = F, na.action = na.pass)
sum(res$acf)
*/
[1] 3.579344
```

**Note:** The function should not show the plot and should handle missing values NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope your real C++ function does more than calling back to R. Otherwise this makes no sense. Anyway:

- `NULL` in C++ and in R are different. Use `Rcpp::Nullable<T>`
- If a R function has default arguments you want to specify, you have to do this in the correct order.
- `[[` has a different meaning in R and C++.
- Why are you returning a `List` when `sum` returns a `double`?

Here the adjusted code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double acfC(NumericVector x, bool plot = true, Nullable<int> lagmax = R_NilValue) {
  Environment stats("package:stats");
  Function ri = stats["acf"];
  Function na_pass = stats["na.pass"];
  List result =  ri(x, lagmax, "correlation", plot, na_pass);
  NumericVector acf = result["acf"];
  return(sum(acf));
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
y = c(arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.7), n = 200),NA)
acfC(y,lagmax = 10,plot = F)


res = acf(y, lag.max = 10,plot = F, na.action = na.pass)
sum(res$acf)
*/
```

Comment: You do understand that this _runs R code_ hence at the speed of R code? You are simply making your life more difficult by calling it from C++.

Comment: @Dirk that's what I wanted to express with the first two sentences. Maybe I should have been more explicit.

Comment: I know _you_ know. I just want to make sure OP knows.

Comment: @Rafael Please see Dirk's comment in case this wasn't clear to you based on my answer.

Comment: I understand what they want to tell me the code will not be faster. I just needed to know how to use the ACF by calling c ++, to make a more complicated project.